# Monitor Docker container loadaverage

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, monitor, cadvisor

Is there any way to monitor the loadaverage inside the container on k8s use java，I need to do this inside the container，I know that what I get through /proc/loadaverage is the loadaverage of the host machine。

Can it only be calculated by the formula for calculating load in linux?

loadn = load(n-1) * e + active * (1 - e)

but it is inconvenient to obtain all processes and threads in the container

Monitor loadaverage of docker container inside the container

Comment: A container runs a single process, and a process doesn't have a load average.  Kubernetes does keep track of the CPU utilization of the process and that can be used in resource limits and via the HorizontalPodAutoscaler.